# ssh won't start >>/dev/null 2>>/dev/null

Tags: centos, ssh

I am running a CentOS 6 server and I have issues with SSH.

My SSH service won't start anymore. I do only have access to some tools using Direct Admin.

At first I couldn't connect to SSH it gave me this message:

```
Jordis-iMac:~ jordikroon$ ssh ***.***.***.***
ssh: connect to host ***.***.***.*** port 22: Connection refused
```

My response was to restart the SSH client in Direct Admin. This didn't work and gave me this message:

```
An error has occurred
Details
/sbin/service sshd restart 2>&1
```

I tried to kill the process ID which worked but then I couldn't start SSH, it gave me the same error.

I have checked the `/var/log/messages` their was no error or anything else about SSH....

The only file with information was DirectAdmins `errortaskq.log` file with this information:

```
2014:06:16-01:14:02: Error starting service sshd : uid 0 gid 0 : /sbin/service sshd start                         >>/dev/null 2>>/dev/null                     
2014:06:16-01:14:07: service sshd didn't start, re-starting it
2014:06:16-01:14:07: Error restarting service sshd : uid 0 gid 0 : /sbin/service sshd restart                         >>/dev/null 2>>/dev/null
```

I am stuck with this. I will only reboot the server when I am really out of options, when it doesn't start I have downtime.

I am able to read and write files, but without sudo (I can at the datacenter).

Comment: Do you have the ability to view the file system? If so, can see if /etc/ssh/sshd_config was modified recently? That may at least give you an idea if it was a configuration issue or not.

Comment: Yes I am able to read the filesystem, the file has been edited today, but I can't see whats wrong. This is the file: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a1563972c5540ace7734

Comment: What happens if you attempt to run the daemon from the cmd line manually:  "/usr/sbin/sshd -f /etc/ssh/sshd_config"

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran your config on my own machine (CentOS 6) and this is what apparently happened:

```
[root@knope ~]# /usr/sbin/sshd -f sshd_config -p222
sshd_config line 150: Directive 'AllowUsers' is not allowed within a Match block
[root@knope ~]#
```

Apparently, AllowedUsers dav was added after "Match User directive", either manually or by an application. It should be after the other users directives.

The best way is to remove that line or move after these following directives:

```
AllowUsers root
AllowUsers jordi
AllowUsers imgios
AllowUsers spot
```

If you don't have a way of updating the file, try to see if you have a backup of it and restore it over the existing on Alternatively, if you installed something that added that line, you can try to uninstall it and see if that line disappears.